# Naming bins in R using the ggplot package

Tags: r, graph, histogram

I am struggeling to name the bins in R with the ggplot package; I tried using the names.args option but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

create a dataframe and then a bar chart in ggplot, using ggplot labels:

```
# my example uses some raster data
require(ggplot2)
require(raster)
r <- raster("myraster.tif")
f <- hist(r, breaks=10)
dat <- data.frame(counts= f$counts,breaks = f$mids)

ggplot(dat, aes(x = breaks, y = counts, fill =counts)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = f$mids,labels = c("0 to 0.1","0.1 to 0.2","0.2 to 0.3","0.3 to 0.4","etc","etc","etc","etc","etc","etc"))
```

Comment: Do I have to use the raster function?

Comment: I do not quite understand why you have to create "r" and "f"? The code does not seem to work for me.

Comment: @Bonsaibubble you gave very little to work on: what sort of data you have, what you want to do with it (make a histogram i guess), where these 'names' appear (the x axis?). I just put up an example that came to mind. No, this example is purely for a raster.